# deleting app a rejected app from itunes connect because I want changed from universel to iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, itunes-app

[image]I changed my app from universal to iPhone and I was not able to validate in the archive. I googled it and I realized that I had deleted my app and submit a completely new app if I want to change it to iPhone. there is no a button to remove my app like you do a "ready for sale" app. here is the thing nobody has downloaded my app yet so it is not like the app will stop working for some devices. I am kinda confused on what to do right help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to give your new iPhone-only app a new bundle id and create a whole new app for it in iTunes Connect.

If you don't want to sell the original universal app, remove it from sale in iTunes Connect. View the app in iTunes Connect. Select "Pricing and Availability". Then select "Remove from sale". Save.

Comment: I cannot there is no button because it is not on sale it is rejected from the app store. If I make a new binary and the app is identical to this rejected one is it fine?

Comment: also, do I have to make a new app ID, a new provision profile and all of that or just make a new app in iTunes connect?

Comment: See my update for details on removing your old app from the store. And yes, you need a new app id, a new profile, and a new app in iTunes Connect.

Comment: I know what you mean and I know that is how most apps are deleted but there is no remove button. I edit a picture to show u what I see please check it out

Comment: Hmmm. Then click the "Edit" link next to Availability and uncheck all territories.

Comment: it is still there but f I keep it there it wouldn't cause any problems right?

Comment: It won't be a problem if it's still in iTunes Connect as long as it's not for sale. I have a few old apps I removed from the store years ago.